# What is the minimum level of certainty so that the witness statement was correct with $50\%$ probability?

Tags: probability

At night there was a serious traffic accident with a hit-and-run offence in front of the main train station.

There is only one witness who claims it was a green taxi.

There are only green and blue taxis in the city, $20\%$ green and $80\%$ blue taxis.

There is no doubt that the accident was caused by a taxi.

(a) What is the minimum level of certainty that the witness must be able to distinguish between green and blue taxis at night so that the witness statement "It was a green taxi." was correct with $50\%$ probability?

(b) How high is the probability of having made a correct testimony if the witness can distinguish between blue and green taxis at night with a $75\%$ probability?

$$$$

For **question (b)** I have done the following :

We consider the following events:

$A$: the taxi in the Accident was green

$B$: the witness identifies the taxi as green

From Bayes' theorem we get: $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B\mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

$P(B\mid A)=0.75$ (if it really was green, the witness identifies it as green with a probability of $75\%$)

$P(A) =0.20$ (since $20\%$ of the taxis in the city are green)

$P(B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)+P(B\mid \neg A)P(\neg A)=0.75\cdot 0.20+(1-0.75)\cdot 0.80=0.35$

So we get $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{0.75\cdot 0.20}{0.35}$$ Is that correct?

Could you give me a hint for **question (a)** ? Do we maybe do the same but with $P(A\mid B)=0.5$ and $P(B\mid A)$ is unknown?

Comment: both  of your approaches look right to me

Comment: The step $P(B | \neg A) = (1 - 0.75)$ looks suspicious because $P(B | \neg A) = 1 - P(B | A)$ shouldn't be true. The complement rule only works w.r.t. the first argument right?

Comment: Ahh ok... $P(B | \neg A)$ is the probability that the witness identifies the taxi as green given that it is blue,right? @0XLR

Comment: Yes. But I don't see how $P(B | \neg A) = 1 - 0.75$. The complement of $P(B | A)$ should be $P(\neg B | A)$ (witness identifies as blue given it was green) not $P(B | \neg A)$.

Comment: But isn't $P(B\mid \neg A)$not the probability that the witness cannot distinguish correctly the taxi?@0XLR

Comment: We are going around in semantic circles. Let's look at the conditional formula instead: $P(B | \neg A) = \frac{P(B \cap A^c)}{P(A^c)}$ whereas $P(B | A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$. The two quantities can't be related in a simple manner because of the denominators mismatch.

Comment: Ok! But how is the correct formula? @0XLR

Comment: I am not aware of any simple formula that relates $P(B | \neg A)$ and $P(B | A)$. Are there any additional assumptions?

Comment: But from the statement of the exercise we have that the witness can distinguish between blue and green taxis at night with a probability of $75\%$, which means that the probability that he cannot distinguigh correctly between blue and green taxis at night is $25\%$, or not? @0XLR

Comment: Yes. But **"cannot distinguish correctly blue and green"** has two parts: **"witness identifies green given it was blue"** and **"witness identifies blue given it was green"**. Both of those are inabilities to distinguish. You are focusing only on **"witness identifies green given it was blue"** part and forgetting about **"witness identifies blue given it was green"**.

Comment: So do we have to consider these two parts at the caclulations? Or what are we supposed to do?@0XLR

Comment: The answer makes the assumption $P(B | A) = P(\neg B | \neg A) = 0.75$ i.e. P(witness identifies blue given it was blue) = P(witness identifies green given it was green) are both 0.75. Then $P(B | \neg A)$ is indeed $1 - 0.75$.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @0XLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q(b). Yes this is the correct answer which  could be given as $\frac{3}{7}.$

Q(a). If $p$ is the probability of correctly distinguishing , then
$$0.5=\frac{0.2\times p}{0.2\times p+0.8\times (1-p)}$$

and $p=\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Is it correct that we have in the denominator the term $1-p$ at question (a) and $1-0.75$ at question (b) ?

Comment: Yes if we assume that the question means that the probability the witness says the correct colour is $p$ - irrespective of which colour it actually was.

Comment: @S.Dolan So the assumption is $P(B | A)$ and $P(\neg B | \neg A)$ are both $0.75$?

Comment: I think that is what is intended by the question.

Comment: @Mary Star. As an experienced  examiner I would not want you to be confused by the comments about your solution. The question could have been stated in a clearer manner but that's no reflection on your answer. You made the expected assumption and answered the question in a clear and correct manner.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)